# Implode data from a Two-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, implode

I think it should not be so difficult to solve but i can’t get the solution.

I’m trying to implode an array in order to have this result :

```
$new_array = "755, 646, 648, 260, 257, 261, 271, 764, ..."
```

Here is my array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 755
            [1] => 646
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 648
            [1] => 260
            [2] => 257
            [3] => 261
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 271
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 764
            [1] => 643
            [2] => 260
            [3] => 263
            [4] => 756
            [5] => 763
            [6] => 762
            [7] => 259
            [8] => 257
            [9] => 758
            [10] => 261
            [11] => 768
            [12] => 757
            [13] => 647
        )
)
```

I know how to do this with a simple array :

```
$newarray = implode(", ", $array);
```

I know how to get the key (with `array_keys`)

```
$new_array = implode(", ", array_keys($array));
```

I’ve tried with `array_map` but without result for the moment.

Coud you help me and point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Show your attempt with `array_map()`, you're probably not far from the solution.

Comment: array_map() will do it for you

Comment: @Rizier123 @SunilPachlangia I've updated my question with `array_map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `array_walk_recursive` function:

```
// $arr is your initial array
$new_arr = [];
array_walk_recursive($arr, function($v) use(&$new_arr){ $new_arr[] = $v; });
```

[DEMO link](https://eval.in/611556)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php

Answer (score 5):

You have to merge inner arrays to one (if our multidimensional array is called `$list`), we can:

```
$merged = array_reduce($list, 'array_merge', array());
```

now you can easily implode it:

```
$string = implode(', ', $merged);
```

echoing given string would print:

> 755, 646, 648, 260, 257, 261, 271, 764, ...

To know you can't implode multidimensional array because it's elements are arrays itself so `array to string conversion` error may arise, thus we should make our array flat, for this purpose you can also check [How to Flatten a Multidimensional Array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array).

Also to know what `array_reduce` do is:

> Iteratively reduce the array to a single value using a callback function.. [see more](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

Answer (score 0):

> try this:

```
<?php 
      $array = array
      (
      array(755,646),
      array(648,260,257,261),
      array(271),
      array(764,643,260,263,756,763,762,259,257,758,261,768,757,647)
      );
      echo "<pre>";
      print_r($array);
      foreach ($array as $value) {
        $newstring[]=implode(",",$value);
      }
      echo implode(",",$newstring);

    ?>
```

You can do it with foreach loop like above

Answer (score 0):

With loop:

```
$array = array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'John Doe',
        'email' => 'john@example.com'
    ),
    1 => array(
        'name' => 'Jane Doe2',
        'email' => 'jane@example.com2'
    ),
);


//function to display values
function ImplodeDataValue($array) {
$tosinglearray=array();
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($array)-1; $i++) {
$tosinglearray[]=implode(',',$array[$i]);
}
return implode(',',$tosinglearray);
}

echo ImplodeDataValue($array);
//returns John Doe,john@example.com,Jane Doe2,jane@example.com2
```